# Getting twice the value when using onTouchEvent

Tags: android

I have a problem with onTouchEvent as it is not giving the proper value. I am making a simple program to show the number of times screen is touched in a textview. I am also using a sensor to increase the value on the textview. I am able to store and increase the value on textview when i use sensor but when i try onTouchEvent the value is increasing twice.
The value is stored in nearCount.
This is the code for onTouchEvent

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        if (nearCount > 0) {

            tv.setText("" + nearCount++);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The touchEvent is working fine..It will call two times because one `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` when you touched and `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` touch is removed

You need to check like thiswith `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

        try {
            if (nearCount > 0) {

                tv.setText("" + nearCount++);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to filter the events in an onTouchEvent:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
int eventaction = event.getAction();

switch (eventaction) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
        // finger touches the screen
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        // finger moves on the screen
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:   
        // finger leaves the screen
        break;
}

// tell the system that we handled the event and no further processing is required
return true; 

}
// see http://www.androidsnippets.com/handle-touch-events-ontouchevent
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly increament value by it because it has two methods `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` when you touched and `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` touch is removed.

So basically you have to call that in your `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` method.

```
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

    try {
        if (nearCount > 0) {

            tv.setText("" + nearCount++);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```